# Objects within subarrays filter query in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have struggled with this for a while so cut to the chase:

I have this object in the database

```
{
  topic: [
    {
      topicName: "Reproduction in plants",
      subTopic: ["Pollination", "Other Topic"]
    },
    {
      topicName: "Plant Cycle",
      subTopic: ["Pollination", "Photosynthesis"]
    },
  ]
}
```

The problem I am trying to solve here is how to make a query that satisfies the following conditions:

1. **Finds all topic that is within the query of topics**
2. **For each of the topic, filter out the results with subtopics inside the topic**

So let's say I want this from a query:

1. Get topics on "Reproduction in plants", of **only** "Pollination" subtopics
2. Get topics on "Plant Cycle", of **only** "Photosynthesis" subtopics

In my current solution:

```
filterQueries['topic.topicName'] = { $in: ["Reproduction in plants", "Plant Cycle"] };
filterQueries['topic.subTopic'] = { $in: ["Photosynthesis", "Pollination"] };
```

It easily satisfies most conditions but runs into the edge case, where it will also fetch objects from "*Plant Cycle*" with "*Pollination*" subTopic.

How to make a query to do what I want from the conditions above?

I will appreciate any help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually "two" problems that are not addressed with such a condition.

The first is that as separate arguments there is nothing to say that values for each property need be within the same element, or in fact if the specific combination actually appears in that element. To remedy that you use an [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) condition within an [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) expression:

```js
 var query = {
     "$or": [
         { "topic": { 
             "$elemMatch": {
                 "topicName": "Reproduction in plants",
                 "subTopic": "Pollination"
             }
         }},
         { "topic": { 
             "$elemMatch": {
                 "topicName": "Plant Cycle",
                 "subTopic": "Photosynthesis"
             }
         }}
     ]
 }
```

That at least selects documents with the combination in elements you require.

But nothing in there can "filter" multiple results, from either the outer `"topic"` or "inner" `"subTopic"` arrays. For that task you need the aggregation framework, since such features are not available to basic projection:

```js
 var pipeline = [
   // Still use the same match to filter possible documents
   { "$match": {
     "$or": [
       { "topic": { 
         "$elemMatch": {
           "topicName": "Reproduction in plants",
           "subTopic": "Pollination"
         }
       }},
       { "topic": { 
         "$elemMatch": {
           "topicName": "Plant Cycle",
           "subTopic": "Photosynthesis"
         }
       }}
     ]
   }},

   // Filter the arrays for matches
   { "$project": {
     "topics": {
       "$filter": {
         "input": {
           "$map": {
             "input": "$topic",
             "as": "topic",
             "in": {
               "topicName": "$$topic.topicName",
               "subTopic": {
                 "$filter": {
                   "input": "$$topic.subTopic",
                   "as": "subTopic",
                   "cond": {
                     "$or": [
                       { "$and": [
                         { "$eq": [ "$$topic.topicName", "Reproduction in plants" ] },
                         { "$eq": [ "$$subTopic", "Pollination" ] }
                       ]},
                       { "$and": [
                         { "$eq": [ "$$topic.topicName", "Plant Cycle" ] },
                         { "$eq": [ "$$subTopic", "Photosynthesis" ] }
                       ]}
                     ]
                   }
                 }
               }
             }
           }
         },
         "as": "topic",
         "cond": {
           "$and": [
             { "$or": [
                 { "$eq": [ "$$topic.topicName", "Reproduction in plants" ] },
                 { "$eq": [ "$$topic.topicName", "Plant Cycle" ] }
             ]},
             { "$ne": [ "$$topic.subTopic", [] ] }
           ] 
         }
       }
     }
   }}
 ];

 // API call to aggregate
 Model.aggregate(pipeline,function(err,results) {
    // results in here
 });
```

Thats the most optimal approach with MongoDB 3.2 using the [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) operation on the arrays. So first you note that the inner `"subTopic"` elements are being tested for matching the conditions along with the outer element to decide which ones to return. This is placed within a [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/), so that the "filtered" content is returned to to the outer array property for further examination.

The outer array is then "filtered" so that only the matching `"topicName"` values are returned, and of course only where the `"subTopic"` array was not "empty" as a result of the filtering.

It is possible to do this in earlier versions, but the typical process with [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) gets very long and costly:

```js
{ "$unwind": "$topic" },
{ "$unwind": "$topic.subTopic" },
{ "$match": {
    "$or": [
        { 
            "topic.topicName": "Reproduction in plants",
            "topic.subTopic": "Pollination"
        },
        {
            "topic.topicName": "Plant Cycle",
            "topic.subTopic": "Photosynthesis"
        }
    ]
}},
{ "$group": {
    "_id": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "topicName": "$topic.topicName",
    },
    "subTopic": { "$push": "$topic.subTopic" }
}},
{ "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id._id",
    "topic": { 
        "$push": {
            "topicName": "$_id.topicName",
            "subTopic": "$_id.subTopic"
        }
    }
}}
```

Whilst it looks simpler to follow, it's a **lot** more costly due to the nature of what `$unwind` does. And of course every aggregation pipeline stage added has it's own processing cost, whereas a modern version can do this in a simple [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/).

Your best bet if you have an earlier version is to use the initial "query" as mentioned, using both the `$or` and `$elemMatch`, and then do the array filtration in code.

Unless of course that you actually need that data to process further in an aggregation pipeline, where you would be stuck with that process in order to "filter".

At any rate, the result you would get:

```js
{
  "topic": [
    {
      "topicName": "Reproduction in plants",
      "subTopic": ["Pollination"]
    },
    {
      "topicName": "Plant Cycle",
      "subTopic": ["Photosynthesis"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Which returns only those matching elements "filtered" in any document.

Comment: Exactly the answer I have been long for. Thanks for the elaborated answer. I will resort to filtering in code, which is rather also complex.

Comment: @minheq As said, the filtering is really ancillary to the actual initial "query" selection to correctly match on your conditions. Your conditions in fact pretty much state exactly what the resulting array contents should look like anyway, so it's easier to just presume that is the returned data rather than manipulate the data to what should already be a pre-destined result.

Comment: I think you are right, i finished writing the algorithm but firstly, it does not feel right about the code. And I am evaluating whether there is a valid business value to force implement this kind of filtering, which could slow all the queries for "questions". And it is also highly unlikely that there is the same subTopic name under two different topics. Query should be the right approach, but I am considering whether it will be easier to just filter the "residue" on the front-end. **Thanks again for your input.**

Comment: On the other hand, I might just use lodash + jsonpath to filter on the application level